# Scp file transfer from Mac laptop to Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, azure, ssh-keys, scp

I try to transfer a VHD.gz file from my Mac to an Azure Ubuntu virtual machine.
From my Mac I've launched this command :

`scp path/to/XXXvhd.gz root@<Ubuntu_VM_IP>:/home/azureuser`

But I have this error : root@XX.XX.XXX.XX: Permission denied (publickey).

Do you know why it doesn't work?
Do I have to establish a SSH connexion?

Thanks in advance for your help

I tried to change the rights on the file with chmod but it is not clear for me if I have to change the rights also for the user, and which user: the one on my local laptop or azureuser on the Ubuntu server

Comment: It's not about the file permission. You need to copy your public key into the VM. Try `ssh-copy-id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root@XX.XX.XXX.XX: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The error means the `root@XX.XX.XXX.XX` doesn't have a publickey.

You need to put your publickey(content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) inside of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of`root@XX.XX.XXX.XX`.

or try `ssh-copy-id`.